# Rotations and inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

As a follow up to my question on [LQ decomposition and inequalities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937520/lq-decomposition-and-inequalities/937530#937530), I'm trying to explore what effect givens rotations have on a system of inequalities.

Suppose I have the simple system $\mathbf{x} \ge \mathbf{b}$, where x and b are vectors, and we're doing element-wise inequality checks.  If I multiply both sides by a rotation like so:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
c & -s \\
s & c
\end{bmatrix} \mathbf{x} \ge \begin{bmatrix}
c & -s \\
s & c
\end{bmatrix} \mathbf{b} $$

(where $c^2 + s^2 = 1$) the inequality no longer holds necessarily, because the givens rotation matrix isn't a [nonnegative matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonnegative_matrix).  However, if the inequality were an equality, the statement *would* still hold.  So the rotation can only change the direction of the inequality.  Possibly for each row independently.

What I'd like to do is predict what effect the rotation will have on the inequalities from its $c$ and $s$ values and account for that.  But I'm not sure how to do that.